# jquery/ajax + django

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've gotten this json object back from django.

I was wondering how do we use ajax/jquery to retrieve just the words that are in bold?

Basically i would like to retrieve the pair of the key - "keyword"

I've tried various methods below but to no avail either getting a undefined or the whole chunk below.

I'm stumped.

```
{ "new_list" : { "a1" : { "exp_datetime" : "2012-03-07 22:13:31",
          "keyword" : "**a1**",
          "sub_datetime" : "2012-02-29 22:13:31"
        },
      "blink182" : { "exp_datetime" : "2012-03-07 22:12:40",
          "keyword" : "**blink182**",
          "sub_datetime" : "2012-02-29 22:12:40"
        },
      "blue" : { "exp_datetime" : "2012-03-07 22:14:44",
          "keyword" : "**blue**",
          "sub_datetime" : "2012-02-29 22:14:44"
        },
      "jolie" : { "exp_datetime" : "2012-03-07 22:08:46",
          "keyword" : "**jolie**",
          "sub_datetime" : "2012-02-29 22:08:46"
        },
      "santa claus" : { "exp_datetime" : "2012-03-07 22:14:13",
          "keyword" : "santa claus",
          "sub_datetime" : "2012-02-29 22:14:13"
        },
      "teleport" : { "exp_datetime" : "2012-03-07 22:09:26",
          "keyword" : "**teleport**",
          "sub_datetime" : "2012-02-29 22:09:26"
        }
    } }
```

Here are the methods i've tried:

```
function updateKeywords(e) { e.preventDefault();
                                 var keyword_form = jQuery(e.target);
                                 alert("Yay Jquery is working!!!");
                                $.ajax({
                                    url : keyword_form.attr('action'),
                                    type : keyword_form.attr('method'),
                                    data : keyword_form.serialize(),
                                    dataType : 'json',
                                    success : function(response) {alert("JSON Data: " + response.new_list.keyword);
                                                },
                                    });
                                    }



                                });
```

Unfortunately, when i put the above, it returns an undefined json data.

When i just put response.new_list, it returns the whole chunk.

Do appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your success callback function, you can loop through the keys of the `new_list` object like so, accumulating a list of keywords as you go:

```
keywords = [];
​for ( var key in response.new_list ) {
    keywords.push(response.new_list[key].keyword);
}
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hans/YAubh/1/).